# How do I stop a form submitting with submit() when I return false within a nested each() function?

Tags: jquery, forms, submit

I need to check a form before submitting but need to loop through some inputs. If an input is invalid, I need to return false and stop the submit, however because the test is within the nested each() function it's not returning false in the outer submit() function:

```
$("#my_form").submit(function() {
    $("#my_form .my_text_inputs").each(function() {
        if ($(this).val() == "bad value")
        {
            alert("Input was invalid");
            return false;
        }
    });
    return true;
});
```

My solution is:

```
$("#my_form").submit(function() {
    var _bSubmitTheForm = true;
    $("#my_form .my_text_inputs").each(function() {
        if ($(this).val() == "bad value")
        {
            alert("Input was invalid");
            _bSubmitTheForm = false;
            return false;
        }
    });
    return _bSubmitTheForm;
});
```

...is there a more elegant way to do this?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`return false` from within the `$.each` will break out of the each loop. So you still want to return there for optimization.

Besides that, I would recommend using [jQuery validate](http://bassistance.de/jquery-plugins/jquery-plugin-validation/) to achieve this same result.